# Fitted Gamma model doesn't go through first datapoint

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, fitting

I have a dataset which looks like this

```
> train
    year OECD_ind steel_ind_2 freight_ind    target
 1: 2006 1.000000    1.000000   1.0000000 1.0000000
 2: 2007 1.035426    1.133137   2.2235587 0.7303400
 3: 2008 1.094234    1.177008   2.0097157 1.6466652
 4: 2009 1.216508    1.249144   0.8228253 1.0142539
 5: 2010 1.307033    1.513894   0.8676799 0.6814760
 6: 2011 1.454713    1.302151   0.4870637 0.3916506
 7: 2012 1.605159    1.417491   0.2894881 0.6383632
 8: 2013 1.762161    1.527313   0.3792380 1.6147156
 9: 2014 1.941333    1.427293   0.3474867 0.8227318
10: 2015 2.140229    1.379996   0.2263931 0.8681335
11: 2016 2.345614    1.351637   0.2116927 0.4189491
12: 2017 2.569241    1.141987   0.3601685 0.4837942
13: 2018 2.729189    1.232870   0.4253945 0.7610337
14: 2019 2.875100    1.568234   0.3897377 0.6527029
```

I am trying to predict the "target" using the other columns. Ideally in a nice to interpret way, so I tried to use a GLM with a log link:

```
> fit <- glm(target ~ OECD_ind + steel_ind_2 + freight_ind ,
+                        family = Gamma(link = "log"), data = train)
> summary(fit)

Call:
glm(formula = target ~ OECD_ind + steel_ind_2 + freight_ind, 
    family = Gamma(link = "log"), data = train)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-0.65732  -0.37871  -0.03702   0.20985   0.67016  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  -0.9660     1.2799  -0.755    0.468
OECD_ind     -0.1936     0.2464  -0.785    0.450
steel_ind_2   0.7152     0.8208   0.871    0.404
freight_ind   0.2399     0.2704   0.887    0.396

(Dispersion parameter for Gamma family taken to be 0.1837372)

    Null deviance: 2.4827  on 13  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1.8608  on 10  degrees of freedom
AIC: 14.339

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

However it does not seem to be predictive e.g. the model does not normalise in the year 2006 which should be "1"

```
> train$pred <- predict(fit, train[,c("OECD_ind","steel_ind_2","freight_ind")],type="response")
> train
    year OECD_ind steel_ind_2 freight_ind    target      pred
 1: 2006 1.000000    1.000000   1.0000000 1.0000000 0.8150797
 2: 2007 1.035426    1.133137   2.2235587 0.7303400 1.1941606
 3: 2008 1.094234    1.177008   2.0097157 1.6466652 1.1573497
 4: 2009 1.216508    1.249144   0.8228253 1.0142539 0.8952095
 5: 2010 1.307033    1.513894   0.8676799 0.6814760 1.0745404
 6: 2011 1.454713    1.302151   0.4870637 0.3916506 0.8191793
 7: 2012 1.605159    1.417491   0.2894881 0.6383632 0.8240831
 8: 2013 1.762161    1.527313   0.3792380 1.6147156 0.8835575
 9: 2014 1.941333    1.427293   0.3474867 0.8227318 0.7884897
10: 2015 2.140229    1.379996   0.2263931 0.8681335 0.7124693
11: 2016 2.345614    1.351637   0.2116927 0.4189491 0.6685882
12: 2017 2.569241    1.141987   0.3601685 0.4837942 0.5710949
13: 2018 2.729189    1.232870   0.4253945 0.7610337 0.6001873
14: 2019 2.875100    1.568234   0.3897377 0.6527029 0.7353143
```

I want to ask if it is because of the type of model I am building or if its the data itself. Any ideas on what to fit to a dataset like this? I have a bunch of other columns to test for predictiveness but I want to make sure the structure of my model is the best it can be.

My data is below:

```
> dput(train)
structure(list(year = c(2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019), OECD_ind = c(1, 1.03542598978172, 
1.09423413052308, 1.21650815799339, 1.30703316362442, 1.45471317882576, 
1.60515878086887, 1.76216102976861, 1.94133329276409, 2.14022939444469, 
2.34561404801045, 2.56924057395179, 2.72918884888304, 2.87509971463427
), steel_ind_2 = c(1, 1.13313665778455, 1.1770079939094, 1.24914350970689, 
1.51389417586601, 1.30215074229159, 1.41749143509707, 1.5273125237914, 
1.42729349067377, 1.37999619337648, 1.35163684811572, 1.14198705748002, 
1.2328701941378, 1.56823372668443), freight_ind = c(1, 2.22355874737605, 
2.00971574518904, 0.822825325293718, 0.867679876770009, 0.487063676661373, 
0.289488078106421, 0.379237957627825, 0.34748668289459, 0.226393139849429, 
0.211692739843334, 0.360168538900102, 0.425394472469706, 0.389737681023965
), target = c(1, 0.730339994039508, 1.64666519383657, 1.01425389617631, 
0.681476035017055, 0.391650575613796, 0.638363202393027, 1.61471560907335, 
0.822731832091845, 0.868133508015245, 0.418949095016058, 0.483794223660976, 
0.76103370971942, 0.652702880970877), pred = c(0.815079658198752, 
1.19416062760147, 1.15734969747307, 0.895209518946654, 1.0745403842771, 
0.81917928281634, 0.824083088775305, 0.883557528204355, 0.788489698973951, 
0.712469340888379, 0.668588186768246, 0.571094915136841, 0.600187337213077, 
0.735314331312731)), class = c("data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), sorted = "year")
```

Comment: Well... the other predictions aren't great either so maybe your model does not fit the data well... or the data is hard to fit. Have you tried some other models? Also Gamma assumes your outcome is in the interval $(0,\infty)$, but yours seems to be bounded from below by 1.

Comment: There may be non-linear relationships as well. My suggestion is to look at the pairwise scatter plots to have an idea of possible associations between the variables or consider doing a more serious EDA.

Comment: Echo what others have said but also when I try to run your data I get this error: `Error: unexpected '<' in:
"ble", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), .intern"`

Comment: Looking at `target` for 2013, it is so far from the years before and after while the predictor variables do not show a similar change, so you will never get a credible model coming close to this from this data.  You can say similar things for other years such as 2016 and 2017.

Comment: Meanwhile not having $1$ in 2006 is much less of an issue: the other variables have been scaled to $1$ in that year but unless it is very special you would not expect the prediction to fit exactly.  You could force it to $1$: one way would be to take logarithms of everything so it is all $0$ that year, build a model with "no intercept" so you predict $0$ that year and then take antilogarithms of the predictions.  That restricts your choice of models substantially, and you would need a justification for doing so

Answer (score 3):

I think @Henry's [point](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/608139/fitting-simple-model-in-r#comment1128532_608139) is the answer here.  You seem to assume that a 'good' fit *should* have $\hat{y} = 1.0$ for the 2006 datum.  There is no statistically grounded reason to believe that—there might be a *scientific* reason to want that, but that's a different issue—from a statistical point of view your software tries to find the candidate parameter values that will maximize the likelihood of the data assuming a conditional Gamma distribution with a log link as a linear function of those three variables.  A fitted function running through $(1.0,\, 1.0,\, 1.0,\, 1.0)$ won't do that for these data and assumptions.  That is, such a function would have a lower likelihood.  You could crowbar the model into doing so, but it would yield a worse *statistical* fit.  At first glance, the fit doesn't seem problematic:

[image: scatteplot matrix]

[image: target vs OECD_ind with fitted line]

[image: target vs steel_ind_2 with fitted line]

[image: target vs freight_ind with fitted line]